# Can I rely on PFUser to cache changes when the user is switching between offline and online

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm building where I want the user to be able to be sometimes offline and sometimes online - when online, i want their stats to sync with the parse server, when offline I want them to be cached locally.

I'm currently duplicating functionality between local saving and PFUser - but it looks like PFUser is doing some kind off caching.

It would be a lot simpler for my code if I could rely on PFUser to handle caching between offline and online - but it's not clear in the docs how it handles it.

Any insight would be great!

Comment: Parse caches some response data in the Cache directory for the app. You would need to test (extensively) to be sure if that private caching would meet your needs...

Answer (score 0):

How about the `saveEventually` method?

Here's an example from Parse's documentation:

```
// Create the object.
PFObject *gameScore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
[gameScore setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1337] forKey:@"score"];
[gameScore setObject:@"Sean Plott" forKey:@"playerName"];
[gameScore setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"cheatMode"];
[gameScore saveEventually];
```

[Here's the link!](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-offline/iOS)

Comment: I've read the docs and it's not clear that this is dependable or if it deals with scenarios such as using the same account across multiple devices and syncing properly.